# Powershell Form Draw Clear

Tags: forms, powershell, draw

Probably really simple, but I cannot for the life of me figure this out.  I am drawing some lines (example below) to a form and when I draw new ones, the old ones don't go away, and I cannot figure out how to clear them.  Interestingly enough when I draw new lines and then resize the window, the old ones go away.  So something is happening during the resize that is triggering what I want.  How can I trigger this manually?

```
$mypen = new-object Drawing.Pen black
$mypen.width = 2
$formGraphics = $mywindow.createGraphics()
$myWindow.add_paint({
    $formGraphics.DrawLine($mypen, 0, 0, $mywindow.size.width, $mywindow.size.height)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, was simple

```
$myWindow.Refresh()
```